# Инициализация умных указателей

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11, инициализация

`std::unique_ptr<X> ptr;`

Будет ли `ptr == nullptr` возвращать `true` для любого типа `X`?

`struct A {std::unique_ptr<X> ptr;}`

`A; A(); A{};`

А в таких случаях для `A.ptr`?

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, в связи с чем возник вопрос. Вы получили какие-то неожиданные результаты при компиляции?

Answer (score 10):

Стандарт явно говорит о конструкторе `unique_ptr` по умолчанию:

> 2 Effects: Constructs a `unique_ptr` object that owns nothing, value-initializing the stored pointer and
>   the stored deleter.
>   3 Postconditions: `get() == nullptr`. `get_deleter()` returns a reference to the stored deleter.

Так что да.

В качестве [примера](http://ideone.com/aEzwG7):

```
struct A {std::unique_ptr<char> ptr;};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unique_ptr<int> x;
    cout << (x == nullptr) << endl;
    A a;
    A b{};
    cout << (a.ptr == nullptr) << endl;
    cout << (b.ptr == nullptr) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Harry уже описал, как ведёт себя конструктор по умолчанию для `std::unique_ptr`. Я же хочу добавить, что типа, имеющего конструктор, совершенно не важно как вы будете определять переменную:

```
A a1;
A a2 = A();
A a3 = A{};
```

Во всех случаях будет вызван конструктор `A` по умолчанию, который в данном случае вызовет конструктор `std::unique_ptr` по умолчанию для члена `ptr`.

Особое внимание можно уделить разве что записям вида:

```
A a4();
A a5{};
```

В случае `a4` не будет создана никакого объекта, а будет всего лишь объявление функции с именем `a4`, не принимающей аргументов и возвращающей тип `A`. В случае `a5` создастся объект, идентичный `a1`, `a2`, `a3`.

Про `a4` более подробно можно ознакомиться в вики: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).